# Print a MATLAB figure to a specific directory

Tags: matlab, printing, figure

I'm using MATLAB version R2016a on a Mac and I'm having trouble printing a figure to a different directory than the current one. Could someone please help me fix my mistake? I have tried the following code:

```
print('Ult_Stress_vs_Temp','-dpng','/Users/Tim/Documents/2-Grad-School/Research/Technical-Paper/Latex/Figures/')
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error using inputcheck (line 40)
Multiple inputs that look like file names: 'Ult_Stress_vs_Temp' and
'/Users/Tim/Documents/2-Grad-School/Research/Technical-Paper/Latex/Figures/'.
Error in print (line 41)
[pj, devices, options ] = inputcheck( pj, inputargs{:} );
Error in ult_stress_temp_plot (line 47)
print('Ult_Stress_vs_Temp','-dpng','/Users/Tim/Documents/2-Grad-School/Research/Technical-Paper/Latex/Figures/') 
>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the full file path as the *first* argument. It's also recommended that you construct your file paths using `fullfile` to better deal with differences between operating systems.

```
filename = fullfile('/Users/Tim/Documents/2-Grad-School/Research/Technical-Paper/Latex/Figures/', 'Ult_Stress_vs_Temp');

print(filename, '-dpng')
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! you are a life saver :)